# Android Version Control and Git

Tags: android, eclipse, git, version-control, git-submodules

I have a large Android Library project of reusable components that multiple application use.  This library is under git control.  The multiple applications that use this Android Library need to point to different commits of the Android Library project (Git Submodules).  But Eclipse does not let submodules be children directories of the current project but rather siblings in the current workspace.  How can I make this work?

For instance if I update the Android Library for and one of the applications, I still want the other application pointing to the original commit of the Android Library.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

For my projects I keep the submodules as subdirectories within the original project and then import the submodules as separate projects alongside the parent.

Comment: eclipse is not letting me use an subdirectory as a shared library.  how were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: You have to import it as a separate project. This is how my setup looks like: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5680413/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-25%20at%2012.57.01%20PM.png

Comment: I am only able to select shared libs from the workspace, not from the libs dir?

Comment: The libs directory was for preference, it used to be in the main directory.

Comment: So how are you referencing different commits between different projects?  this is my problem.

Comment: The submodule is its own project, its own git repo. The commits are its own. The main project only holds a reference to the commit number.

Comment: exactly, so how are u maintaining that reference.  whenever my workspace is cleaned the library uses the head commit of the library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11762/discussion-between-handlerexploit-and-jjnford)

Comment: I'd like to do this but Eclipse doesn't let me import - complains that it's "already added". How did you go about this??? I'm sure that I'm importing the same project from two locations - one is the actual project, another is the submodule.

Comment: @ScottW Just add the .project file to the .gitignore and rename the project name to for example 'ParentProject-LibraryProject'. This is how I handle it.

Comment: Yuck, I want to be able to update changes easily. See [this question I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325205/how-do-i-manage-git-submodule-subprojects-in-eclipse)

Comment: @ScottW If you want to stick with Eclipse (w/o maven) then you are going to be limited this way. I do this for a ton of projects and it works perfectly. The only downside is I have quite a few library specific projects but I just add a filter for them.