# How do I manage git submodule subprojects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

(In case it matters, these are Java Android projects)

Project **A** is a library project.

Project **B** depends on **A**. For ease of project management across the board for other people instead of just me, **A** is contained within **B** via a git submodule.

This means, if I want to make changes to *both **A** and **B***, I will have the following:

1. Project **A** itself
2. Project **B**
3. **B**'s submodule of **A**, let's call it **A'**. Same code, same project name, different location on disk.

Ideally I would like to be able to meet the following conditions:

1. Be able to modify **A** itself directly within Eclipse.
2. Be able to modify **B** and have it build, referencing **A'**, all within Eclipse.
3. I don't really need **A'** as an imported project / no need to modify it, but I'd like it to automatically build its jar file and have that be referenced by **B**.

**What I've tried:**

1. Simply importing both **A** and **A'**: Doesn't work, because Eclipse cannot import two projects with the same name. I can't simply change the name either because it's a submodule; would have to do that *every git update*, unacceptable.
2. Adding External Library reference to **A'**, keeping it out of Eclipse entirely: actually not too bad of a solution, but requires at least one external build of it from the command line (using `ant`) before it will work...not the most convenient.
3. Doing a Source Link: Not the cleanest because **A** (and subsequently **A'**) have multiple source folders within them, so I'd have to update each time I add or remove source folders within **A**. I'd rather just use the jar directly.

Is there a way to keep this all in Eclipse, or should I do something like #2 but with an added external build command to call `ant` on **A'**?

Comment: Why not import B and A' but not A?

Comment: Because #1 states I wish to be able to easily change / modify **A**.

Comment: I was questioning the requirement. Yes you want to be able to modify project A, but why not just the project A that's at location A' ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It seems that my own question here addresses the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022243/developing-a-git-library-project-thats-also-a-submodule-of-another-project

Comment: @Trevor Never found one, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain again what's wrong with @karmakaze's suggestion to import B and A'? Why does that prevent you from modifying A'? Do you have some build system that requires A be at the location A as opposed to A'?

Comment: @AdrianTaylor it doesn't really solve the problem. I'd have to basically add only B's version of A and no other A, to be able to modify A. Meaning multiple projects that rely on A can't really be done, plus I'd have to do a lot of swapping/importing each time I change focus on another project. It's a question about managing, not building.

Comment: Scott, thanks, that's obvious in retrospect, I just hadn't thought of the case where you've got multiple projects depending on A.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation. Import B as existing (android) project into eclipse after you git clone it. Make sure project A is initialized and updated (via git).

Now, do file->import existing project (android if A is an Android project) and go to where the submodule A project is inside of your project B and add it.

Now you have two separate projects in eclipse. You can change both projects, and it will all be under Project B, because that is where both projects are located.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is specifically for Android, have you looked into Android libraries?

In my case I have a free (B) and a paid for (C) version of my app. Both share a common code base (A).
In eclipse I make A an Android library and both B and C use this library and all 3 are separate git repos. With this setup, changes I make in A are automatically available in B and C and I only need to maintain one code base for each project. No fancy build scripts/configs.

I think this sort of simplicity is what you were after? Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got your setup right:

Project A : src
+ /projecta.jar (binary of project A)

Project B : /src
 + /lib/Project A/src as submodule
 + /lib/projecta.jar (binary of project A)

..now you change A-A' and compile it, wanting to test it before pushing/commiting, right?
is it ok for you to just have the jar in B, or do you need the source within project B updated to A'?

first case:
have an ant file compile in project A and deploy it to B as well
that ant file is not part of project a, its just a local workaround
(its useful to have it in the ant view of eclipse)

Sketch:

```
<property name="projectb.libdir" value="..."/> set appropriate place in project B

<javac fromdir="./src" todir="./build" ...><fileset ... /></javac>

<jar /> from build to projecta.jar

<copy /> projecta.jar to projectb.libdir
```

Alternative is to create a .jardesc in eclipse, so you can run "create jar" on rightclick.

is that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars Milestone 5 (4.5.0M5) has Multiproject-support. You only need to import "Existing Project" from Subfolder.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a project build system to track your dependencies (that is what they are good for).

I would you suggest to use `gradle` (preferable IMHO but check which one fits better on your context) or `maven`, both can handle subprojects pretty well and can generate the eclipse configuration for you.

Comment: Example and further specification would be appreciated.

Comment: @Warpzit, I'm giving him a different approach to the problem, both tools are well documented e.g (from maven Getting Started documentation): http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_build_more_than_one_project_at_once

Comment: Generate .. what Eclipse configuration? Can I just get that magic configuration manually at first? Then I'll consider this.

Comment: @ScottW all eclipse project's configurations (including dependencies between the projects). I already had done this setup in different ways (ant, maven and gradle) and for a client I had move his very messy build away from eclipse (we kept using it as an IDE, only moved away from rely its internal build system). There is no silver bullet, you will have to learn the tools you choose. IMHO, Eclipse isn't the best tool for the job, but follow your instincts.