# Developing a Git library project that's also a submodule of another project

Tags: android, git, git-submodules

I have an Android application under development which makes use of a separate library project of my own. These two projects are stored in separate Git repositories. The application project references the library project by means of the `.gitmodules` file.

I'm now trying to work on both of these projects together (the application and the library) on a new machine. I cloned the application project, which resulted also in the library project being automatically cloned into my ~/git/ directory as well. So far so good.

I notice also that in Eclipse Package Explorer, the library project root has a commit hash within brackets (e.g. `[MyLibraryName 0123ABC]`). This presumably means that the library clone is from a certain commit point, and I understand that I could update this (i.e pull in the latest commits for this library) using `git submodule foreach git pull`.

Question is, what is the best way for me to continue separately developing the library project now? I tried to modify a file and stage it, but when using Team->commit, the dialogue didn't list the modified file. I assume this might be something to do with it being a submodule, pointing at a particular commit.

Should I clone my library project again, completely separately into a different subdirectory, and import as a separate project into Eclipse in order for me to do work on that library?

Comment: If you're comfortable with command line git, you can commit changes to your submodule by navigating to it first. No clue when it comes to Eclipse's Package Explorer.

Comment: You still have two independent projects so you need to work within the appropriate project to do the commit. In addition you need to make sure you are on a branch (in the sub-project), rather than a detached head, so that you can push your changes to your golden repo.

Answer (score 0):

Having read various other SO questions, it seems apparent that there's no elegant solution for this. The steps I eventually took to solve this are:

- Assuming not done so already, clone the application repository that makes use of submodules. Import all projects into Eclipse workspace, including the submodule repository (or repositories). Note that the submodule repository is a repository within the main application repository, and it's not on a particular branch; it's a reference to a particular commit (detached head).
- In the Package Explorer, rename the submodule project that was imported. I gave it a name that relates to the application repo it's inside of. For instance, for an application project called ABCD, rename it from SomeLibrary to SomeLibrary_ABCD.
- Next, clone the library separately from its own Git repository. Now, the point of renaming the submodule project is that it's now possible to import the Eclipse project from the standalone clone of the library repository, without Eclipse giving the "Some or all projects can not be imported because they already exist in the workspace" error.

Having done this, we have SomeLibrary_ABCD project which is not on a branch but points to a particular commit, and is a submodule of project ABCD. That submodule is updated using `git submodule foreach git pull`. Then, we have project SomeLibrary, which is on a branch (e.g. master).

My planned workflow is to locally switch the application project to point at my 'standalone' project of the library instead of the submodule version when I want to do development on the library. I then commit changes to SomeLibrary.

Any better suggestions than this (or corrections to anything I've stated) would be appreciated - but for now this is my own answer to the problem.